# pandas filter string from column by regex condition and replace it

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, filter

Here I have a string from a pandas DataFrame.

`https://www.gofundme.com/3hgsuu0,https://twitter.com/dog_rates/status/840632337062862849/photo/1`

what I want to do is to iterate through all rows find the twitter url and delete the **NOT** twitter url from the column.
Goal is to just have twitter urls in the column not 2 or more urls.

what I did is

arch_drop_new1.expanded_urls.apply(lambda x: str(x).split(",")[0])

which gives me all strings before the `,` that appears in the rows where more than 1 url is, contained.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPqrD.png)

Comment: I think you may use `arch_drop_new1['twitter_urls'] = arch_drop_new1['expanded_urls'].str.extract(r'(https://twitter\.com/\S*?)(?:,http|$)', expand=False)`

Answer (score 0):

You can `.str.extract()` the values with

```
rx = r'(https?://twitter\.com/\S*?)(?:,\s*http|$)'
arch_drop_new1['twitter_urls'] = arch_drop_new1['expanded_urls'].str.extract(rx, expand=False)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1pK4i1/1).

Note `extract()` will extract the first occurrence of the pattern (here, only Group 1 value since there is a single capturing group in the pattern) from each row.

**Details**

- `(https?://twitter\.com/\S*?)` - Group 1: `https://twitter.com/` or `http://twitter.com/` and then 0 or more non-whitespace chars, as few as possible
- `(?:,\s*http|$)` - a non-capturing group matching `,`, 0 or more whitespaces, and then `http` or end of string.